# how to generate a random route

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am a beginner and I got a coding challenge where I got the following directions: N,S,W,E

In the challenge I need to generate 10 random steps(directions). Also, I am not allowed to have duplicate neighbours. For example, [n,s,w,e,w,e,n,n,w,e] is not allowed.

Here is my code but it doesn't work right. It generates routes but with duplicate neighbours

```
import random

def road_generator():
    directions = ['n','s','w','e']
    road = []
    for x in range(10):
        road.append(random.choice(directions))
    keep_going = True
    while keep_going:
        for x in range(1,len(road)):
            if road[x] == road[x-1]:
                road[x-1] = random.choice(directions)
            else:
                keep_going = False
    print(road)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    road_generator()
```

Can someone please explain to me what I did wrong with my code and how to fix this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to define the function:

```
import random

def road_generator():
    directions = ['n','s','w','e']
    road = []
    while len(road)<10:
        street = (random.choice(directions))
        if not road:
            road.append(street)
        if road[-1] != street:
            road.append(street)
    return road

print(road_generator())
```

Output:

```
['e', 's', 'n', 'e', 'n', 'w', 'e', 'w', 'n', 'w']
```

Comment: `if len(road) == 0:` would be better written `if not road:` and `road[len(road)-1]` is written `road[-1]` in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You check for the duplicate neighbours, but instead of updating at x, you update at x-1. This can cause duplicacy in x-1 and x-2. So updating the line

```
road[x-1] = random.choice(directions)
```

to :

```
road[x] = random.choice(directions)
```

should do the trick.

Also, you terminate the loop once a pair of duplicate neighbours is found. There may be more duplicates later. So, rather you should let the loop run till range 10, and update the code to:

```
#remove keep_going variable
x = 1
while (x<len(road)):
    if road[x] == road[x-1]:
        road[x] = random.choice(directions)
    else
        x = x+1
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it you can just check the duplicacy while appending them to the list.

```
import random

def road_generator():
    directions = ['n','s','w','e']
    road = []
    for x in range(10):
        road.append(random.choice(directions))
        # to check duplicate neighbours 
        if x!=0:
            # This loop iterates until both values are same
            while road[x] == road[x-1]:
                road[x] = random.choice(directions)
    print(road)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    road_generator()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import random
def road_generator():
    directions = ['n','s','w','e']
    road = []
    for x in range(10):
        temp = random.choice(directions)
        while x > 0 and temp == road[x-1]:
            temp = random.choice(directions)
        road.append(temp)
    print(road)
```

Answer (score -1):

**Not an answer to your specific question but a possible different approach for you**

So basically you start with a random route without caring about neighbours. You then iterate the route infinitely, replacing any neighbouring directions with a new random one until you have a good route.

Maybe you could try rewriting it so you don't need to do the brute force random replacing.

I advice you to take a step back and figure out what actually makes a duplicate neighbour. Then try to generate a route without having to ever go back and check it.